# Find out the words from a python list which contains permutation of another word

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a python list which contains various words. I have to take Input from the command line using `sys.argv` and have to find out all the permutation words from the list. 
For example :

```
import sys
words_list=['llaa','lala','alal','aall','abcd','egg','adore', ...]
word=sys.argv[1]
```

and I entered `laal` as the sys.argv[1].
Here I want to list all the permutations of `laal`  from the `words_list`. This words_list may contains thousands of words. Please tell me the most efficient way to do it. I don't want to use `sorted` or `collections.Counter` method.

Comment: You should probably comment on your responders so that they know if they are helping you or not.

Comment: You say 'which contains the characters laal' Does that mean in any order or the specific sequence? i.e., clearly `laal` matches `laal` but does it match `lala`?

Comment: I meant to say all the words which can be make using the characters `laal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT

Now I see what you want is a match for every letter including the number of letters.

First put the argv[1] into a list, and then sort it, so you don't have to sort it every time. This avoids using `sorted`:

```
ARG = list(sys.argv[1])
ARG.sort()
```

Then define a function to determine if a word matches:

```
def anagram_match(w):
    w = list('w')
    w.sort()
    return w == ARG
```

Finally, a list comprehension will filter out the words that do not match, leaving only the ones that do:

```
[w for w in words_list if anagram_match(w)]
```

---

Earlier response:

I would use a list comprehension:

```
[w for w in words_list if sys.argv[1] in w]
```

if you want to check for if *any* of the letters are in the word, check for if there is a set intersection:

```
[w for w in words_list if set(sys.argv[1]).intersection(w)]
```

Comment: It will returns the words which contains substring of sys.argv . I don't wanna search the substrings but the complete words. like `lpease` and it's right word is `please`,`saleep`, `asleep`

Answer (score 1):

There is no "efficient" way using only python and a list. This will always be an O(n) algorithm.

You can simply do:

```
import sys

words_list=['llaa','lala','alal','aall','abcd','egg','adore', ...]
search_word=sys.argv[1]
for word in words_list
    if search_word in word:
        print word
```

Comment: It will search the substring in the word. But i want all the words which can be formed using the combination of characters of sys.argv[1]. Thanx for reply

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, something like this will show you all strings that contain every letter contained in your test word:

```
words_list = [ ... whatever ... ]
word = sys.argv[1]

def contains_all(x, y):
  for ch in x:
    if not ch in y:
      return False
  return True

[x for x in words_list if contains_all(word, x)]
```

This would give `['llaa', 'lala', 'alal', 'aall']` in your given example...

It's not horribly efficient - in particular, sorting and uniquifying `word` would reduce the number of comparisons needed to be made. Making a set from the word would be one way to do that.

An alternate reading of your question might be that you want to find all words that are permutations of the given word - e.g. the same result as above, but something like `lalafoo` would not match because it contains letters that are not in the test string. However, your question is a bit vague on exactly what you want.

Comment: What exactly I want is that if I enter the word `lpease`it should return me words `please`,`saleep`, `asleep` which can be form using the characters in the sys.argv[1] 1.e `lpease`

Comment: @SajidAhmad You should probably re-word your question then, because finding all words that are permutations of a given word is a bit different than the literal interpretation of finding "all the words from the list which contains the same character used" - "lalalalalalalala" contains the same characters used in "laal", but it is not a permutation...

Comment: I don't want `lalalalala` `laal` have four characters only which can form `laal`, `llaa`,`aall`, `alal`. length of the word should be same